# How to take max value from from certain numbers in a row of a numpy array using input?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an excel file that looks something like this:

| array | boys | girls | food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5453 | 534 | 312 | 114 |
| 5453 | 662 | 882 | 534 |
| 6453 | 553 | 109 | 123 |
| 2534 | 223 | 435 | 664 |

I have an input that asks for a code, and prints the max value of the row not including the code. I was thinking of using the input and finding the index of it, but I am stuck

```
import numpy as np

    
numbers = np.genfromtxt('numbers.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=True)

choiceCode = input('Enter a code')    
Row = numbers[choiceCode] #I tried to find the index of the input given

print(np.max(Row[1:4]))   ##then tried finding max of it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is arguably a much clearer and simpler way to solve this problem.  It also handles the case where there is more than one match of code in the first column (I see the revised example data you provided now includes duplicate values).

```py
numbers = np.array([
       [5453.,  534.,  312.,  114.],
       [5453.,  662.,  882.,  534.],
       [6453.,  553.,  109.,  123.],
       [2534.,  223.,  435.,  664.]
])
choiceCode = 5453

rows = numbers[:, 0] == choiceCode  # find matches
print(np.max(numbers[rows, 1:], axis=1))  # print maxes of all matched rows
```

Output:

```py
[534. 882.]
```

Comment: your right this does look more simpler

Comment: what is the point of specifying axis = 1?

Comment: If you try this example with `choiceCode = 5453` without `axis = 1` you will get `882.` instead of `[534., 882.]`. You didn't specify what you want to happen when `choiceCode` matches more than one row!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  If you google search for 'how to find a value in numpy array' you will find this and some other ways.

```py
numbers = np.array([
       [1224.,  485.,  540.,  582.],
       [1679.,  398.,  423.,  391.],
       [9626.,   23.,   25.,   58.],
       [9806.,  150.,   83.,  120.]
])

choiceCode = 9626
i = np.where(numbers[:, 0] == choiceCode)[0]  # 1st dimension
if i.size > 0:
    print(np.max(numbers[i[0], 1:]))  # take first match
```

Output:

```
58.0
```

***Update:***

According to [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), `np.where` is a shorthand for `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()` when only `condition` is provided and using `nonzero` directly is preferred :

```py
i = np.nonzero(numbers[:, 0] == choiceCode)[0]  # take first match
if i.size > 0:
    print(np.max(numbers[i, 1:]))
```

Comment: I am getting         ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Comment: Try my updated code with `numbers` defined.

Comment: @kr003: Consider accepting the answer since it helped you solve the problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Bill I am still not sure what  the [0] refers to in np.where(numbers[:, 0] == choiceCode)[0]

Comment: Not sure if you read the documentation for `np.where` before asking this but assuming you did, I agree it is confusing. See the note saying "when only `condition` is provided, this function is a shorthand for `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`". `np.nonzero` returns a tuple of indices as arrays. This is because it is designed to find all nonzero values in any n-dimensional array. Since we're only interested in the first match in a 1-d vector, we take only the first element in the tuple. Note: I probably should have used `np.nonzero` directly instead of `np.where`.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the preferred method.

Comment: @Bill is it possible to use np.where to check if a number in a column exists in multiple data sets?